# How do I creat a foreign key reference to a composite key?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, data-annotations, code-first

I am using Entity framework 4.1 in MVC 3 application. I have an entity where I have primary key consists of two columns (composite key). And this is being used in another entity as foreign key. But part of the key needs to be used in more than one navigation property. How do I create the relationships? I have tried the following without any luck because you can't seem to specify more than one navigation property in a foreign key annotation:

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), MaxLength(40)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Company { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), MaxLength(40)]
    public string EventReference { get; set; }
    [Key, ForeignKey("AssignedEmployee, Organiser"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public Employee AssignedEmployee { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AssignedEmployee"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public Person Organiser { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Organiser"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public string OrganiserId { get; set; }
}
```

If this can't be done using data annotations can anyone shed any light on how to do it in code?

Comment: can you change the database to have an EmployeeId as the key? your life would be so much easier. Also can you describe in words your domain you are trying to model, especially the relationships cardinality?